# Installing Wine on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, wine

I'm trying to get Wine installed on Snow Leopard but have run into a few roadblocks.

First I saw this page: http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX/Installing

Since the link to the pre-built binary seemed to link to some other (similar but different?) program called WineBottler, I decided to try to go with `MacPorts` or `Fink`. So, first to try MacPorts: http://www.macports.org/install.php

I downloaded the dmg, and was told I needed `Xcode` to install it. However, in order to download Xcode I need to be registered as an Apple Developer? http://www.macports.org/install.php

So I scrapped that and went to Fink instead... which also needs Xcode: http://www.finkproject.org/download/srcdist.php. All I want to do is run a windows app on Snow Leopard. Do I seriously need to sign up as an apple developer first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an iTunes account, it's the same login for the Apple Developer. WineBottler is not a bad choice. It is basically the Wine code boxed into an easy-to-use OS X application. MacPorts or Fink might be overkill just to run Wine.

Also consider running Windows in a VM such as [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/), or [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/). In my experience, virtual machines are much more stable than Wine for running Windows applications.

Comment: Right, but then you need to actually own a Windows license.

Answer (score 1):

I think u can find XCODE on the OS (Snow Leopard) disc somewhere